# How to get the Sort Property of the Range Class?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split an Excel file into multiple files.

I am getting

> "Unable to get the Sort Property of the Range Class"

on `.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Sort.Range ("A1"), Header:=xlNo`

```vb
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Sort.Range ("A1"), Header:=xlNo
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Do you really have `.Sort.Range("A1")` with no space inbetween, or is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0):

`Sort` should be passed key1 argument instead like:

```
.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Range("A1"), Header:=xlNo
```